# Updating Field Based on another Field using UpdateCursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, python-2.7, valueerror

I have a feature class in a FGDB called `LeasePlans`. It contains a field called `Property_Ref`. I then have a `CSV file` with a field called `SAPNO`. For the feature class, I need to check does the value in `Property_Ref` occur in the `SAPNO` of the CSV and if so I need to add the word `Archived` to the new field called `Status`. Below is the code I have thus far, I'm not sure what is wrong with it, I'm getting an error `ValueError: too many values to unpack` but I suspect that is the least of my problems.

```
#Archives Historic SAP Numbers
import arcpy

fc = "U:/Data/Leases.gdb/LeasePlans"
changes = "U:/Data/To_be_Deleted.csv"

#New Field Criteria
field_Name = "Status"
field_Nametype = "Text"
field_NameVal = arcpy.ValidateFieldName(field_Name)

#Adds the new field if it doesn't already exist
fList = arcpy.ListFields(fc,field_Name)
if not fList:
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, field_Name, field_Nametype, "", "", "")

#List comprehension for IDs
ids = [i for i, in arcpy.da.SearchCursor
       (changes, "SAPNO") if i != None]


Relevant_Fields = ['Property_Ref', 'Status']

#update cursor to Insert 'Archived' rows
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (fc, Relevant_Fields) as cursor:
    for SAPNO, in cursor:
        if SAPNO in ids:
            row[1] = 'Archived'
            cursor.UpdateRow()

del cursor
```

Comment: What is the full error message seen, including line number, when you run the code that you have presented?

Comment: The full error I get is: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\Data\Update_Cursor_Archived.py", line 26, in <module>
    for SAPNO, in cursor:
ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit your csv and remove everyting but the Sapno values and then execute code below. It will check if the value in field Property_Ref exists in the csv file and update.

```
import arcpy, csv

fc = r'C:\database.gdb\feature_class'
codefile = r"C:\folder\file.csv"

with open(codefile, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    sapno_list = [k[0] for k in reader]

fc_fields = ['Property_Ref','Status']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fc_fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in sapno_list:
            row[1]='Archived'
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            print "Did not find value for Propetry_Ref: {0}".format(row[0])
```

Comment: The code runs but it doesn't update any records in the `Status` column. An example of a value present in both the `CSV` and `Property_Ref` is `1217/006`. It does print `Did not find value for Property_Ref: 1217/006`. Perhaps the `/` is causing an issue?

Comment: What if you add print sapno_list above fc_fields line? What gets printed out?

Comment: When I add `print sapno_list` above the `fc_fields` line it prints the `CSV` contents in the format: `['0043/004'], ['0063/721'], ['0091/401'], ['0157/711']`

Comment: @Dunuts I have changed `sapno_list = [k for k in reader]` to `sapno_list = [k[0] for k in reader]`, try again!